# Get specific values from controller function

Tags: laravel

I started learning Laravel and I am trying to achieve the following:

Get data from database and display specific field.

Here is my code in the controller:

```
public function show()
{
    $students = DB::select('select * from students', [1]);
    return $students;
}
```

Here is my route code:

```
Route::get('', "StudentController@show");
```

That all works for me and I get the following displayed:

```
[{"id":1,"firstname":"StudentFirstName","lastname":"StudentLastName"}]
```

How can I get only the "lastname" field displayed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to remove `[1]` here as you didn't define any parameters in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DB::select('select * from students')
```

is a raw query that returns an array of stdClass objects, meaning you have  to loop through the array and access properties:

```
$students[0]->lastname
```

You can also use the query builder to return a collection of objects:

```
$collection = DB::table('students')->get();
$student = $collection->first();
$student->lastname;
```

Lastly, using the query builder, you can use pluck or value to get just the last name.  If you only have one user, you can use value to just get the first value of a field:

```
DB::table('students')->where('id', 1)->value('lastname');
```

I strongly advise you to read the Database section of the Laravel docs.

Answer (score 1):

`$students[0]['lastname']` will return the last name field, the [0] will get the first student in the array.

I would recommend creating a model for Students, which would make your controller something like this:

```
$student = Students::first(); // to get first student
$student->lastname; // get last names
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, that returns the following error: Undefined index: lastname

Comment: @DaanT Because it is in an array you may need to do $student[0]['lastname'] to grab the first student.

Comment: Doing that returns: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: @DaanT $students->first()->lastname; ?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the one column returned, you can use `pluck()`

```
public function show()
{
    $last_names= DB::table('students')->pluck('lastname');
    return $last_names;
}
```

This will return an array of all the students' lastname values.
If you want just one, you can access it with `$last_names[0]`

As a side note, your `show()` method usually takes a parameter to identify which student you want to show. This would most likely be the student's id.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can accomplish this task. Firstly, I advise you to use the model of your table (probably `Students`, in your case).

Thus, for example,to view this in the controller itself, you can do something like this using [dd helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-dd):

```
$student = Students::find(1);
dd($student->lastname);
```

or, using [pluck method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck)

```
$students = Students::all()->pluck('lastname');
foreach($students as $lastName) {
  echo $lastName;
}
```

or, using [selects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects)

```
$students = DB::table('students')->select('lastname');
dd($students);
```

Anyway, what I want to say is that there are several ways of doing this, you just need to clarify if you want to debug the controller, display on the blade...

I hope this helps, regards!